# notification in Windows 10 (winrt + desktop) Not work subgroup

Tags: c#, notifications, windows-runtime

I try show Toast(not tile) Notification from desktop app. (c#)
Without groups all ok,i see text and image, but groups(subgroups) hidden.
Why?

I create xml via NotificationsExtensions.Win10
I will post raw xml if need.
Thanks.

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<toast launch="https://toster.ru/q/327775?e=3995419#comment_1108015">
  <visual>
    <binding template="ToastGeneric">
      <text>Today will be mostly sunny with a high of 63 and a low of 42.</text>
      <group>
        <subgroup hint-weight="1">
          <text hint-align="center">Mon</text>
          <image src="file:///C:/Users/user/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/android.forms.test/Lobster.Home.Toster.ru.Windows/bin/Debug/images/icon_activity_comment.png" hint-removeMargin="true" />
          <text hint-align="center">63°</text>
          <text hint-align="center" hint-style="captionSubtle">42°</text>
        </subgroup>
        <subgroup hint-weight="1">
          <text hint-align="center">Tue</text>
          <image src="file:///C:/Users/user/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/android.forms.test/Lobster.Home.Toster.ru.Windows/bin/Debug/images/icon_activity_comment.png" hint-removeMargin="true" />
          <text hint-align="center">57°</text>
          <text hint-align="center" hint-style="captionSubtle">38°</text>
        </subgroup>
        <subgroup hint-weight="1">
          <text hint-align="center">Wed</text>
          <image src="file:///C:/Users/user/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/android.forms.test/Lobster.Home.Toster.ru.Windows/bin/Debug/images/icon_activity_comment.png" hint-removeMargin="true" />
          <text hint-align="center">59°</text>
          <text hint-align="center" hint-style="captionSubtle">43°</text>
        </subgroup>
        <subgroup hint-weight="1">
          <text hint-align="center">Thu</text>
          <image src="file:///C:/Users/user/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/android.forms.test/Lobster.Home.Toster.ru.Windows/bin/Debug/images/icon_activity_comment.png" hint-removeMargin="true" />
          <text hint-align="center">62°</text>
          <text hint-align="center" hint-style="captionSubtle">42°</text>
        </subgroup>
        <subgroup hint-weight="1">
          <text hint-align="center">Fri</text>
          <image src="file:///C:/Users/user/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/android.forms.test/Lobster.Home.Toster.ru.Windows/bin/Debug/images/icon_activity_comment.png" hint-removeMargin="true" />
          <text hint-align="center">71°</text>
          <text hint-align="center" hint-style="captionSubtle">66°</text>
        </subgroup>
      </group>
    </binding>
  </visual>
</toast>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You could use this awesome app to test your Toasts and see it before you send it and set the XML data:
[Notifications Visualizer - Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/notifications-visualizer/9nblggh5xsl1)

For your problem, I believe it's a common issue where you missed a closing tag or your xml code order for the visuals isn't correct, the solution is to use the Notifications Visualizer app.

**Update 1:**

Since you can't download the app, here's the XML code they used.. I tried it on my machine and it's look good:

[image: Weather Toast]

```
<toast>

    <visual baseUri="Assets/Apps/Weather/">
        <binding template="ToastGeneric">
            <text>Today will be sunny with a high of 63 and a low of 42.</text>

            <group>
                <subgroup hint-weight="1">
                    <text hint-align="center">Mon</text>
                    <image src="Mostly Cloudy.png" hint-removeMargin="true"/>
                    <text hint-align="center">63°</text>
                    <text hint-style="captionsubtle" hint-align="center">42°</text>
                </subgroup>
                <subgroup hint-weight="1">
                    <text hint-align="center">Tue</text>
                    <image src="Cloudy.png" hint-removeMargin="true"/>
                    <text hint-align="center">57°</text>
                    <text hint-style="captionsubtle" hint-align="center">38°</text>
                </subgroup>
                <subgroup hint-weight="1">
                    <text hint-align="center">Wed</text>
                    <image src="Sunny.png" hint-removeMargin="true"/>
                    <text hint-align="center">59°</text>
                    <text hint-style="captionsubtle" hint-align="center">43°</text>
                </subgroup>
                <subgroup hint-weight="1">
                    <text hint-align="center">Thu</text>
                    <image src="Sunny.png" hint-removeMargin="true"/>
                    <text hint-align="center">62°</text>
                    <text hint-style="captionsubtle" hint-align="center">42°</text>
                </subgroup>
                <subgroup hint-weight="1">
                    <text hint-align="center">Fri</text>
                    <image src="Sunny.png" hint-removeMargin="true"/>
                    <text hint-align="center">71°</text>
                    <text hint-style="captionsubtle" hint-align="center">66°</text>
                </subgroup>
            </group>
        </binding>
    </visual>

</toast>
```

BTW, I've tried your xml code in the Visualizer app and it showed nothing!
Try to tweak the xml code I provided to fit your needs...

Comment: Yes, i know, thanks. But Windows Store does not work on this computer, i can not install any app?i try it later from another. 
I use example with weather, groups are hidden

Comment: To use my code, you need change image's paths, when i use incorrect paths, i get notification with default Text, when i use correct image paths i get my text without subgroups.
I show nitifications from WPF COMMON DESKTOP app, not from windows store app. Difference between your and my code - only images.

Comment: To see my code in visual app you need change image path on existing image or create(copy) image with same full path
I have not got used baseuri, but my full path works fro logo.You can remove images and try without it, it does not works for me withou images too.
Very thanks, i'm will later to play with visual app.